# prolog finding first cousins in family

Tags: prolog

Trying to do a prolog question to find first cousins!

```
/* first person is parent of second person */
parent(a, b).
parent(b, f).
parent(a, d).
parent(f, g).
parent(a, k).
parent(f, h).
parent(k, l).
parent(f, i).
parent(k, m).
parent(l, t).
parent(b, e).

sibling(X,Y) :- parent(Z,X), parent(Z,Y), not(X=Y).

grandparent(X, Z) :-
    parent(X, Y),
    parent(Y, Z).

cousin1(Child1,Child2) :-
    grandparent(Y1,Child1),
    grandparent(Y2,Child2),
    not(sibling(Child1,Child2)),
    Y1=Y2 .
```

Seems to be working, but is there a way to stop it from returning true if the same child is input?

EDIT: final answer

```
cousin1(Child1,Child2) :-
    parent(Y1,Child1),
    parent(Y2,Child2),
    sibling(Y1,Y2).
```

Comment: hint1: change in "cousin1" the condition "grandparent(Y2,Child2)" to "grandparent(Y1,Child2)", and remove Y1=Y2. Performance improves.

Comment: hint2: define "cousin1" using only "parent" and "sibling".

Comment: hint1 simplifies it a great deal, not sure why I always complicate things. Not sure how to do hint2?

Comment: Two persons are cousins if their parents are siblings.

Comment: Yet another example of me over complicating things. Thanks!!!

Comment: You are welcome. Do not worry, is a subject of practice.

Comment: Your second approach seems correct. But perhaps you should post it as an *answer* not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final answer!

```
 cousin1(Child1,Child2) :-
     parent(Y1,Child1),
     parent(Y2,Child2),
     sibling(Y1,Y2).
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a .not-self predicate, which returns false if the children are equal.  Add that to your cousin predicate.